# Interpreting learning curves

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-evaluation, supervised-learning

There is really few examples online regarding interpreting learning curves and they are all of different type.It is quite confusing to me honestly.May I just ask:

1. How should we interpret them?What should we look out for?
2. How can we discover overfitting or underfitting using it

(The first image metric is MAE,the second image ,metric is recall)

[image: First Pic]
[image: Second Image]